# Wtforms- render IntegerRangefields within formfield within fieldlist iteratively

Tags: javascript, for-loop, macros, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I have a really long form (100+ fields). It consists of various field types including `IntegerRangeField`,`FormField`,`FieldList` and more.

Here is a simplified example:

```
class SubForm(Form):
    first_name=TextField('First')
    age=IntegerRangeField('Age')
class MainForm(Form):
    height=IntegerRangeField('Height')
    weight=IntegerRangeField('Weight')
    friend_list=FieldList(FormField(SubForm),'Friends')
```

The `IntegerRangeFields` do not display the slider value by default, so I use a javascript function `JSfunction` to display the slider value in the template.

Everything is rendered using a macro:

```
{% for field in form if field.type not in ["HiddenField","CSRFTokenField"] %}
    {% if field.type in ["IntegerRangeField"] %}
        {{field.label}}
        {{field(min=0, max=100, oninput="JSfunction(this)")}}
        <output><script> document.write() </script></output>
    {% else %}
        {{field.label}}
        {{field}}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I am having trouble referencing the `IntegerRangeFields` within the `FormField` within the `FieldList` so that I can apply `JSfunction` to them and display the slider value. How can I do this? As of now, all the fields/widgets render, but sliders within `FormFields` within the `FieldList` do not show the slider value.

Thanks in advance!

edit:
IntegerRangeFields that aren't in the Fieldlist appear as sliders, and moving the slider displays the slider value next to the slider:

i.e. `height ----------|| 100`

IntegerRangeFields that are in FieldList do not have the JSfunction applied so they do not have an integer value next to the slider:

i.e.  `age ||----------`

I'm having difficulty iterating through to the IntegerRangeFields within FormFields within FieldLists.

Comment: what is it rendering in your HTML, can you give an example of one of the integer fields render?

Comment: I edited the main post to show examples of what is rendering and articulated the main problem better. I suspect I need to do it with multiple for loops. I cannot seem to pin it down though.